# jquery off not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't unbind event use off.

I was trying to bind `click` event, then bind `mouseleave` event and callback unbind `click`, but not working.
`el` is dom create and append by script that's why I use `document.on... el`

so I tried below include commented code for test not working too.... do I miss understand something?

jquery-1.11.1.min.js

https://jsfiddle.net/70t6jtns/

```
var el = $('div')
$(document).on('click', el, function() {
  console.log('oncli')
});
//$(document).on('mouseleave', el, function() {
  //$(document).off('click', el, function() {
    //console.log('offcli')
  //});
  //$(document).off('click', el);
  el.off('click');
//});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) doesn't accept jQuery objects as the second argument, so `$(document).on('click', el, function() {...` doesn't make sense.

The main issue is that you're using event delegation in one case but expecting a directly-attached handler in the other case. You're attaching your `click` handler to `document`, but then trying to *detach* it from a specific element (`el`). You have to remove it from the same thing you attached it to.

If you want to attach the handler to `el` and detach it later, use `el` consistently as the target:

```
el.on("click", function() { ...
```

then

```
el.off("click");
```

If the handler has to be delegated, you'll want to be sure, again, that you're removing the same thing you're adding. So for instance,

```
$(document).on("click", "selector-for-the-element", function() { ...
```

then

```
$(document).off("click", "selector-for-the-element");
```

Comment: thanks for reply but the el is create and append by script

Comment: @user1775888: That's fine, just hook the event after it's created. Your code shows that you have the element as of when you hook up the handler.

Comment: a little confuse so the on syntax usage can be `$(document).on("click", "selector-for-the-element", ...`  right?  but the `"selector-for-the-element` should be selector like .n #n  can not be jquery object

Comment: *"First, on doesn't accept individual elements as the second argument, so $(document).on('click', el, function() {... doesn't make sense."* - Actually it does because `el` is just a selector.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: No, `el` is a jQuery object, not a selector: `var el = $('div')`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek  Yes, you are correct about previous jsfiddle. Should have been `el` at second parameter. The event will not be delegated to only `el` https://jsfiddle.net/70t6jtns/2/

Comment: @guest271314 Because there is only a single `div` on the page add two and click both.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Click outside of `div`, check value of `event.target` at `console`. The event should not be dispatched if attached only to `div` element.

Comment: Considering *"speaking loosely"* I sure seem to be getting a lot of heat for a single word. My point is that jQuery *can* take a jQuery object as the parameter and will treat it like it's a selector, hence why it *"accepts"* it (*will still function*).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: If so, it's [undocumented behavior](http://api.jquery.com/on) and thus not something to be relied upon.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True, guess I need to find better ways to say *"here is a cool thing X can do!"* without trying to seem like a jerk.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Well, if you were, you weren't the only one, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Because i added the on listener on document and trying off with element. that was the issue in my case.